# If $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, then $A-A^2 \neq I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose a matrix $A \in M_{3\times3}(\mathbb R)$, then $A-A^2 \neq I$.

I know that I should contradict that statement, and use the fact that a $3\times3$ matrix has at least one real eigenvalue. However, I can only think of substituting $A$ for
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i
\end{bmatrix}$$

and solving a system of $9$ equations in $9$ variables.

Any ideas? Thanks ahead.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue, and $A-A^2=I$, then $\lambda-\lambda^2=1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, super ! thanks, I got it

Answer (score 1):

Since 3 is odd,  the characteristic polynomial of $A $ has a real root. Is  this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ would be $\mu(x)=x^2-x+1$. However, $\mu(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. So, $A$ has no real eigenvalue.